# is a free cellular action of a discrete group over a cellular complex always properly discontinuous?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

I think that the answer is "yes" for free simplicial actions over simplicial complexes: a non trivial element g of the group G must map a simplicial simplex to a different one, because of brower theorem and the free hypothesis. From this the result follows easily I guess.